# Реальный физический размер экрана

Tags: java, android

Какой есть для этого метод? Есть несколько методов, которые выдают размер приложения. И даже если оно во весь экран, эта величина оказывается меньше реального размера устройства.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WindowManager w = activity.getWindowManager();
Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
d.getMetrics(metrics);

// since SDK_INT = 1;
int widthPixels = metrics.widthPixels;
int heightPixels = metrics.heightPixels;

// includes window decorations (statusbar bar/menu bar)
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 17)
    try {
        widthPixels = (Integer) Display.class.getMethod("getRawWidth").invoke(d);
        heightPixels = (Integer) Display.class.getMethod("getRawHeight").invoke(d);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
}

// includes window decorations (statusbar bar/menu bar)
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17)
    try {
        Point realSize = new Point();
        Display.class.getMethod("getRealSize", Point.class).invoke(d, realSize);
        widthPixels = realSize.x;
        heightPixels = realSize.y;
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
}
```

Вот такая "шляпа" нашлась  [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/how-to-get-screen-dimensions-as-pixels-in-android). Тем не менее работает.